NextAuth problem: how do I restrict access to Credentials logged-in user but also use Dropbox and Instagram Providers?
Nextjs/NextAuth project. The app is controlled by session based on a login via the Credentials provider. Dropbox provider is used to provide AccessToken. The problem is that the Credentials session user is overwritten by Dropbox data when the user signs in to Dropbox. Adding the Credentials user's ID to the session succeeds in the NextAuth session, but that property is not returned by either useSession or getServerSession. Any modifications that I make in the NextAuth callbacks do not get to useSession or getServerSession.
I am using the NextAuth signin page (multiple providers).
The flow goes: User signs in with Credentials. Session.user has user info. Needs to upload an item to Dropbox, is passed to NextAuth sign in page for Dropbox. Signs in to Dropbox.  session.user data is now Dropbox user info. And the user is authenticated for the app by the dropbox signin.
I need to handle a couple of things differently.

I need to persist the Credentials user data no matter what other signin Providers may be used subsequent to a Credentials signin.
I need to limit authentication to the Credentials signin only.

This is the Credentials log output:
  user: {
    name: 'Credentials username',
    email: 'credentials email',
    image: undefined
  },
  expires: '2024-06-14T13:16:20.919Z',
  accessToken: '{"InstagramToken":null,"DropboxToken":null}',
  userId: '4'
}

This is that same log after the user signs in to Dropbox:
nextauth session:  {
  user: {
    name: 'dropbox username',
    email: 'dropbox email',
    image: 'image stuff'
  },
  expires: '2024-06-14T13:16:37.738Z',
  accessToken: '{"InstagramToken":null,"DropboxToken":"dropboxtoken stuff"}',
  userId: 'dbid:dropbox id'
}

And to top it off, the session that is returned by getServerSession or useSession does not include session.userId:
after getServerSession:  {
  user: {
    name: 'Dropbox username',
    email: 'Dropbox email',
    image: 'Dropbox image stuff'
  }
}

